# Failed to emit precompiled header for bridging header error after adding test target

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoapods, bridging-header

So im building an iOS app using cocoa pods, everything builds properly locally and on the build machines when I push it.

I tried to add a test target and the code still works perfectly locally but suddenly after adding this test target sometimes my code builds fine but most of the time it just says it failed to emit a precompiled header for bridging header and gives me a few errors with the headers I’m importing.

Just wondering if anyone has ever run to this and it might have any ideas? If you need some more information let me know! I already did some research and tried a few things such as seeing my pod file deployment version is the same as all my targets.